# Surjective ring homomorphism from polynomial to complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, ring-theory

> Let $\Bbb R[x]$ denote the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb R$. Find a surjective ring homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb C$ and compute its kernel.

I don't know how to begin because polynomial can have infinite coefficients but complex numbers are in the form $a+bi$.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest surjective ring homomorphism $\Bbb R[x]\to \Bbb C$ takes the polynomial $x$ to $i\in\Bbb C$, but in fact, assigning any nonreal complex number would work.

Observe that the image of $x$ solely already determines the map as it supposed to be a homomorphism.

Comment: +1. Aside: the map you've described is the evaluation homomorphism at $i$ (perhaps this will allow the OP to compute the kernel more easily).

Comment: How can I just choose x? Should I have to allow the input to be all possible polynomials since that is the ring I was given ?

Comment: And also if every single value of x is taken to i then how is it surjective ?

Comment: No, *not every polynomial* maps to $i$, only the element '$x$' of $\Bbb[x]$. Then for example the polynomial $x^2-x+2$ maps to $i^2-i+2=1-i$ as the homomorphism respects ring operations ($+,\,-\,\cdot$).